# Compiling sstrip from ELFkickers for Ubuntu10.04 : asm/elf.h problems

Tags: linux, gcc, executable, demoscene

I'm playing around with creating tiny executables under linux. My attention has come to a formerly used tool from Muppetlabs.com named sstrip from the ELFkickers collection (http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/elfkickers.html)
It strips even more bytes from an ELF executable than strip alone.
And it seems that it was in the Ubuntu feeds until HardyHeron but now its gone without a trace.
So I tried compiling myself, but the asm/elf.h header seems to be on a new position and gcc bails out with:

```
gcc -ggdb -Wall -W -o sstrip sstrip.c
sstrip.c:12:21: error: asm/elf.h: No such file or directory
sstrip.c: In function 'readelfheader':
sstrip.c:70: error: 'ELF_DATA' undeclared (first use in this function)
sstrip.c:70: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
sstrip.c:70: error: for each function it appears in.)
sstrip.c:72: error: 'ELF_CLASS' undeclared (first use in this function)
sstrip.c:77: error: 'ELF_ARCH' undeclared (first use in this function)
sstrip.c: In function 'getmemorysize':
sstrip.c:138: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
sstrip.c: In function 'modifyheaders':
sstrip.c:205: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
make: *** [sstrip] Error 1
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Or does anyone know where to find sstrip in a PPA?
Maybe an alternative?

Comment: Maybe http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/arch/x86/include/asm/elf.h.

Comment: The error probably doesn't mean that elf.h is "in a new position", it probably means that you need to *install* it. Try installing kernel-headers.

Comment: I did install all kernel headers and also pointed the compiler to use them. But still the compilation fails with a ton of error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ wget http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/pub/software/ELFkickers-3.0.tar.gz
$ tar xf ELFkickers-3.0.tar.gz
$ cd ELFkickers-3.0/
$ make
```

Then you can find the **sstrip** binary in the **sstrip/** directory. If you get errors, please post the output of the `make` command so we can help you.

Comment: Maybe a little late, but thanks! The new version compiles correctly - its 3.0a now :)